# Converting an image with simple shapes to polygons

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, arcgis

I have a simple GIS layer image exported from an ArcGIS server, which I now want to convert back to polygons. 
What is the best method to go about doing that?

1. Write my own script (what's best then- triangulation? line/edge tracing?)
2. Use some tool? (opencv? something else?)

[image: png image of polygons (each color represents a different polygon)]

Comment: before starting any research in that direction, try to get hold of the data, that image was generated from

Comment: of course, but that's not possible, I have to solve it as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image you show is rasterized, so you cannot go back to the *original* polygons.
However, with some simple connected component analysis you can extract all contiguous blobs (of the same color). These can be completely represented by their boundary (anything outside the blue lines).
Your new polygons are now these boundary pixels. Of course, you can apply polygon simplification to reduce the number of actual nodes in the polygon. OpenCV has several such algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way is to use the [From Raster toolset in ArcGIS](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/About_converting_from_raster_data/00120000000n000000/). The tool you'll probably want to use is [Raster to Polygon](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Raster_to_Polygon/001200000008000000/). You can run it directly in ArcGIS for Desktop or call it in a Python script. You can also run it in ArcGIS for Server if you wish. All license levels of ArcGIS include the Raster to Polygon tool.

Keep in mind that Raster to Polygon will try to extract *all* parts of the image to polygons, including boundaries, so you'll have some cleanup to do. Hopefully that's as easy as selecting all the boundary features (i.e. the ones that were blue in the image) and deleting them.

Answer (score 0):

Although Gary's answer using argGis seems better, if you just have this raster image, you can extract the contours by just keeping the bluish pixels (simple for loop on the pixel data to create a mask, or even possibly `Mat mask = orig == cv::Vec3b(255,0,0)` (change the value with the actual border pixel color). Then you can find the connected components of each contour, using for example [`cv::floodFill`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=floodfill#int%20floodFill%28InputOutputArray%20image,%20InputOutputArray%20mask,%20Point%20seedPoint,%20Scalar%20newVal,%20Rect%2a%20rect,%20Scalar%20loDiff,%20Scalar%20upDiff,%20int%20flags%29)` and use 
[cv::approxPolyDp](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=approxpoly#void%20approxPolyDP%28InputArray%20curve,%20OutputArray%20approxCurve,%20double%20epsilon,%20bool%20closed%29) to vectorize the points.